# distutils setup.py install - 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I am trying to use a particular python/numpy library [rmcgibbo/logsumexp](https://github.com/rmcgibbo/logsumexp), but can't get it to install. Here is the trace when I run `setup.py install` as per the instructions:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    ext_modules = [ext]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 573, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 970, in run_command
    cmd_obj = self.get_command_obj(command)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 846, in get_command_obj
    cmd_obj = self.command_obj[command] = klass(self)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

[Contents of `setup.py`](https://github.com/rmcgibbo/logsumexp/blob/master/setup.py)

What could the problem be?

Comment: you got `duplication` on namespace. be careful creating namespace. 
Maybe you are using is not compatible modules.
make sure that the support which module which library.
class names may vary depending on the version.
most likely you are experiencing a shortage of your version of the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing the build_ext module, but not specifying what the callable is in that module. What you actually want do is change what you have in your try block to this:

```
try:
    from Cython.Distutils.build_ext import build_ext
    src = ['sselogsumexp.pyx', 'src/logsumexp.c']
except ImportError:
    from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
    src = ['sselogsumexp.c', 'src/logsumexp.c']
```

I tested this with the distutils.command.build_ext module. If you look in that module you will notice there is a class called build_ext, so in order to call the 'callable', you will need to import as specified in my example. I ran the setup.py with the code change and it worked.

Comment: I sent a pull request to the author to fix this.

https://github.com/rmcgibbo/logsumexp/pull/4

Comment: Just to let you know the pull-request was accepted, so you can just update your repo and you should have the latest changes